# CSS Target IE6 Validly

Tags: css, internet-explorer-6, overflow, hidden

basically im in a little dilemma... As usual, IE6 is messing up some tiny line of CSS.

All i need to fix everything is:

```
overflow:hidden;
```

Thats it. But, heres the problem. This is for a uni assigned piece of coursework and they say only 1 css file which must be valid. And no conditional comments :S so there goes my plan. Is there any way to target IE6 ONLY (not 7+ etc.) and still maintain a valid CSS file?

PS: before any of you say, well you should rethink your CSS etc, I have, its for a CSS dropdown menu and a nested element is stretching my link container so i need overflow set to hidden. Only IE6 needs this :S

EDIT MY SOLUTION:

```
html>body .allbrowsersceptIE6 {
    overflow:visible;
}

.onlyIE6 {
    overflow:hidden;
}
```

It works because all other browsers use the first value and ignore the second one unless the second has !important on it :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it comes down to using hacks as your only option: http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/csshacks2.shtml

So, you want to apply that rule to #menu or whatever:

```
* html #menu { overflow: hidden; }
```

Comment: Although i didnt test it, it validates so I award you with the answer. Check my op for my solution tho :D